# Doubt regarding logic ...

Tags: logic

p:She is innocent

q:she is clever
r:she is rich

I am asked to obtain $\neg p \land \neg q \land r$..
I can write : She is neither innocent nor clever but she is rich.

But can I write this as: She is not innocent and clever but she is rich.

Because both have same meaning so both must be correct I believe. Please explain whether I am correct or not.

Comment: The first way is more accurate. She is not innocent and clever says that she is either not clever or not innocent.

Answer (score 1):

> She is not innocent and clever.

This is ambiguous and could be interpreted (by a logician, rather than a human) as:

It is not the case that she is both innocent and clever.

What you actually intend is that

(She is not innocent) and (She is not clever).

Most humans (other than attorneys) might well have interpreted the first statement, as you intended.